# Solve logistic differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Task: $\frac{du}{dt} = u(1-\frac uA)$ with $u(0) = u_{0}, 0 < u_{0} < A$

I know that this is a variable separation type, however, I have no idea to solve it. 
what should be the next step?

Comment: $\int dt=\int \frac{du}{u(1-\frac{u}{A})}$.

Comment: Separate the variables and partial fraction decomposition will help.

Comment: Great minds think alike.

Comment: @JJacquelin $t = log|u(1-\frac{u}{A})|$   How can we deform to draw a solution trajectory

Comment: @S.Ky. You have not to do that. Just integrate after partial fraction decomposition. I suppose that you know what partial fraction decomposition is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: we have $$-\frac{u'(t)}{\frac{u(t)(-A+u(t))}{A}}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

You could also solve this logistic equation as a Bernoulli equation setting $v=A/u$,
$$
\dot v=1-v.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $\frac{du}{dt} = u(1-\frac uA)$

$\frac{du}{dt} = u(\frac{A-u}{A})$

$\frac{1}{u(A-u)}\,du = \frac{1}{A}\,dt$

$\int\frac{1}{u(A-u)}\,du=\int\frac1A\,dt$

$\int\frac{1}{Au}+\frac{1}{A(A-u)}\,du=\int\frac 1A\,dt $

$\frac 1A\big[\ln(u)-\ln(A-u)\big]=\frac 1At+c $

$\ln(\frac{u}{A-u}) = t+C$

Answer (score 1):

Hint
$$\frac{du}{dt} = u(1-\frac uA)$$
$$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac 1 {A}u(A-u)$$
$$\int \frac{du}{u(A-u)} = \int \frac {dt} {A}$$
$$\int \frac{du}{u(A-u)} =  \frac t {A}+K$$
Use decomposition of fraction and integrate
$$\int \frac{du}{u(A-u)} =  \frac t {A}+K$$
$$\frac 1 A(\int \frac{du}{u}-\int \frac{du}{(u-A)}) =  \frac t {A}+K$$
$$\int \frac{du}{u}-\int \frac{du}{(u-A)} =   t +K$$
$$......$$